# Providing a qualitative description of the results from DBSCAN clustering

Tags: qgis, clustering, concave-hull

I have run a DBSCAN clustering algorithm in QGIS 3 on bus stops in my specific study area where my minimum cluster size is 50 and maximum distance is circa 9km.

After this I created a concave hull of the clusters and found the centroid of each of these.

How can I qualitatively define that centroid in the context of this methodology that is easy to understand for a non-technical reader?

Comment: What is the purpose of this study? I think a qualitative explanation would make more sense if given in terms of *why* you clustered the bus stops.

Comment: Maybe come up with a concise term for the bus stop cluster *regions*. ("Bus stop cluster regions" is my working term; try to find a better term that makes sense in the context of your study.) Then describe the cluster centroids as "the center point of each region" (many people will be confused by the term "centroid," while everyone understands what "center" means).

Comment: @csk thank you. In short, the purpose of the study is to find areas of densely situated bus stops and relevant routes for potential staff to use for new retail developments. I totally agree that a qualitative explanation is needed as to why this approach was taken. The qualitative explanation as to what these points represent would be used in presentations to potential developers.